# Pagination of query ignoring the LIMIT clause in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, orm, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a query that would only return 2 results, and by following the documentation I get the query to run, however the `limit` is still set to `20` by default.

Here is how the query is built:

```
$upcomingMeetings = $this->Meetings->find('all')
  ->where(['Meetings.user_id' => $this->Auth->User('user_id')])
  ->andWhere(["Meetings.date >= " =>  date('Y-m-d') ])
  ->order(['Meetings.date' => 'ASC'])
  ->limit(2);
```

The result is being passed to the view like following:

```
$this->set('upcomingMeetings', $this->paginate($upcomingMeetings));
```

Here is the query that is being run on the database:

```
SELECT 
  Meetings.id AS `Meetings__id`, 
  Meetings.date AS `Meetings__date`, 
  Meetings.user_id AS `Meetings__user_id`, 
FROM 
  meetings Meetings 
WHERE 
  (
    Meetings.group_id = 7 
    AND Meetings.date >= '2016-01-14'
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  Meetings.date ASC 
LIMIT 
  20 OFFSET 0
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no default limit, unless you are using for example the paginator. If  that is the case, then please mention that and show the relevant code regarding pagination configuration.

Comment: Should work. Are you sure you are actually executing that code you are showing us? Do you apply any modification to `$upcomingMeetings` anywhere else?  Can you please post the executed SQL query you see i.e. in debugkit?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick responses. I have just updated the questions with information you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When paginating a `Query` object, CakePHP will ignore the `limit()` clause and use the value defined in the `$paginate` configuration array instead.

This is what can be concluded after inspecting [the source code](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Controller.Component.PaginatorComponent.html#149).

Try adding the following to your controller:

```
public $paginate = [
    'limit' => 2,
];
```